# Rails Strong Params - Permit indexes for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm dealing with a multiple file uploader, and the params I receive from my uploader is something like:

```
"pdf_conta"=>{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faed4374738 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161010-6502-go0te.pdf>, @original_filename="AVENIDA.pdf", @content_type="binary/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"conta[pdf_conta][0]\"; filename=\"AVENIDA.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: binary/octet-stream\r\n">, 
"1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faed4374440 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161010-6502-e5t82z.pdf>, @original_filename="BANDEIRANTES.pdf", @content_type="binary/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"conta[pdf_conta][1]\"; filename=\"BANDEIRANTES.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: binary/octet-stream\r\n">}}
```

and I can't permit that param, 'cause if I put something like `:pdf_conta => {}` on my permitted params, it gives me the error for `Unpermitted parameters: 0, 1`. How can I permit that hash to have as many indexes as it needs? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try `:pdf_conta => []` ?

Comment: It will give me unpermitted params for pdf_conta, since conta is hash, not an array

Comment: So what if you convert it into an array?  `params['pdf_conta'] = params['pdf_conta'].values`

Comment: A hash with integer keys is an array.  You will never see in the params a param[:attr][0] = "value", instead it is a hash with '0' => "value"